# SLF4J vs. Jboss Logging

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I've noticed that many of the redhat/jboss frameworks have started migrating to jboss-logging where they've previously used SLF4J, for example hibernate 4.0.  Jboss-logging can delegate to SLF4J

What are the advantages of using jboss-logging over e.g. SLF4J with Logback?

Answer (score 13):

Technically, none. I suspect the move is mostly a political one.

JBossLlogging is itself just an API much like SLF4J, and therefore just delegates to an actual logging implementation. By using their own abstraction, the insulate themselves from changes to the SLF4J API (which has already shown itself to be non-backwards-compatible across versions).

Whether or not this is a good idea is debatable.

Comment: The SLF4J API as exposed to users has not changed since version 1.0. In that sense, SLF4J is backward compatible since the beginning. You are surely talking about SLF4J *internals* which indeed change across major versions.